# Encore on Symfony 4.4: trouble with tapable plugin

Tags: symfony, webpack

Updating an old Symfony application (born with 2.0...) I'm trying to make it run with Symfony 4.4. I had to switch from Assetic to Webpack Encore, but looks like I have some trouble. Following the docs, I required Webpack Encore via Composer, than installed it with yarn. But when I run 'yarn encore' after setting up my app.js file, I get this error:

[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/home/gillo/www/mappatureS4/webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] Error: @symfony/webpack-encore tried to access tapable, but it isn't declared in its dependencies; this makes the require call ambiguous and unsound.

Required package: tapable (via "tapable")
Required by: @symfony/webpack-encore@npm:1.1.2 (via /home/gillo/www/mappatureS4/.yarn/cache/@symfony-webpack-encore-npm-1.1.2-0af8607bc0-84a60ace3a.zip/node_modules/@symfony/webpack-encore/lib/webpack-manifest-plugin/).

Can't understand how to solve it...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is caused by a conflict between Yarn 2 and webpack-encore.

Try adding this to your `.yarnrc.yml` file:

```
nodeLinker: node-modules
```

See these GitHub issues for more information:

- [symfony/webpack-encore#730: Error: webpack-cli tried to access webpack](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/issues/730)
- [symfony/webpack-encore#655: Support for Yarn PnP](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/issues/655)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and the solution I found is to add the package to package.json

`yarn add --dev tapable`

Comment: Looks like it's not the solution for me.  

Usage Error: Package "tapable" is already listed as a regular dependency - remove the -D,-P flags or remove it from your dependencies first